# evaluateJavascript is not executing function

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

How do i execute javascript function at runtime, the function to load the chat window does not get executed

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    let javascript =
    "const params = {typeId: ‘someid’, callback: getContextCallback} loadChatWindow(params)"
    evaluateJavascript(javascript, completion:{ _ in })
}
```

Comment: If you have two JS statements in a single line, you have to separate them with a semicolon. Also, your single quotation marks are not valid, you have to use '.

Answer (score 0):

try catching your error in evaluateJavascript completionHandler to see if your javascript string is correct or not (you need semicolon to separate the js statements as mentioned in the comment). also, evaluateJavascript is webView's method so it should be called like this:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascript) { (result, error) in

print(error as? String)}
```